# Undefined object when trying to retreive state object from oidc-client callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, openid-connect

After authenticating the user and redirecting back to my `Home` component I'm trying to retrieve the user profile from the `signinRedirectCallback`function like so:

```
usermanager.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        setUser(data)
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e)
    });
```

logging the user (data) shows the correct object. However, using `setUser(data)` and then later trying to retrieve it in my return gives me `read property of undefined`.

Here's the function code:

```
function Home() {
    const usermanager = new Oidc.UserManager(authConfig)
    const [user, setUser] = useState(localStorage.getItem("user") || {})

    React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", user);
    }, [user])

    usermanager.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        setUser(data)
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e)
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Home component</h3>
            <p>{user.profile.unique_name}</p>
            {console.log(user)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

What I would like is to be able store the user in a state to be able to use later on in the application.

This is the finished and working code:

```
function Home() {
    const usermanager = new Oidc.UserManager(authConfig)
    const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || {})

    React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    }, [user])

    usermanager.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (data) {
        setUser(data)
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e)
    });

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={user.profile}>
            <div>
                <ComponenentThatUsesUserContext />
            </div>
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why there should be any data after page reload? It's all will be default. You can store data between redirects in cookies, localstorage, redirect link...

Comment: @RTW But isn't that what I'm doing in my useffect and `localstorage` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stringify your user data before you store it:

```
 localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
```

and parse it back to your object:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thanks!